# Can you index ECL items with Search Integration 4 Tridion (SI4T)?

Tags: content-delivery, ecl, search, si4t

I understand that Search Integration 4 Tridion (SI4T) can index binaries only if they are linked from other published Components (or perhaps Pages).

**Can SI4T index, or be made to index, binaries coming from another system via the External Content Library?**

### Background

I'm reviewing a scenario where the same PDFs are *uploaded* and used separately in both Tridion Docs and Tridion Sites.

Sites indexes the PDFs using Search Integration 4 Tridion (SI4T).

To reduce the writer and editor steps, I'd like to recommend having PDFs exposed to Tridion Sites with an External Content Library (ECL) integration. PDFs can be uploaded and published once in Docs and reused in Sites as needed.

Comment: hey man, do you want to push entire content of the binary to Search? If so, you can modify SI4T templating to push the data to Search in whichever format you like.

Comment: Thanks, Marko. Feel free to post that as an answer since that is a use case for ECL, where it can indeed publish things from systems that don't have a delivery element. The other idea we've discussed would be a deployer extension that grabs and indexes binaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take on this would be to modify SI4T templating to push data in the search. For example, if you work with any DAM, you can get in templating via API all the info you want to push to the search engine, plus, you can even push resolved URLs, which can be used later in website.